# Are wild Pokémon capped at level 30?

Tags: pokemon-go

I caught Pokémon that required Power Up Stardust of 5000 before, and I was at level 30 or 31, and I could power up a Pokémon all the way with 6000 stardust needed at that time.

I thought it is by "remainder arithmetics", meaning it is modulo math, that if you are at level 27, then the maximum level of Pokémon that you catch will be level 26 (calculated by the Pokémon ID number, modulo your level, to get the remainder as the level of Pokémon that you caught).

Now I can power up a Pokémon all the way to needing stardust 7000, but the Pokémon I caught are still requiring a maximum of 5000 to power up. Does it max out at this level?  (I think they are level 30 Pokémon).  I think for a hatched egg, the level max out at 2500, and they are all level 20 Pokémon.

Answer (score 5):

With the recent introduction of the [weather system](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/hoenn-pokemon) in Pokemon Go, wild Pokemon are no longer capped to level 30.0 if they are captured while the weather conditions are favorable to them.

For instance, if it's snowing in the game, Ice and Steel Pokemon appearing on the map are no longer capped to level 30.0, while all the others still remain capped to level 30.0.

[The maximum level that these weather-boosted wild Pokemon can reach is 35.0](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/7ihyyd/weather_effect_allows_wild_pokemon_to_be_caught/).

Answer (score 4):

Pokemon hatched from eggs will be, at most, level 20.0.

Pokemon caught in the wild, however, will be, at most, level 30.0.  See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t7su2/does_this_mean_that_after_level_30_wild_pokemon/).

This means that once you hit level 30, Pokemon encountered in the wild will no longer keep up with your level.

However, you are still able to power up your Pokemon to level 40.0, in increments of 0.5.

Comment: I mean when you catch a Pokemon, will it be a level 30 Pokemon at most.  That is, you won't be able to catch a level 31 Pokemon directly

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I realized that as I hit submit, hold on, I'm about to update it.

Comment: interesting, for those data `MaxEncounterPlayerLevel: 30` are they code in the app or are they data sent to the app by the API call?

Comment: It was datamined from the app some time ago.

Comment: It is interesting that the source code was in the app at that time... if it was compiled into pure machine code (processor machine code), then no such info should be visible

Comment: @Jerry Based on charts like [this one](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/stardust/), max Pokémon level is 40.0.