# Do brilliant pokémon stay brilliant after you catch them?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-eighth-generation

In the new generation of Pokémon there are [Brilliant Pokemon](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/brilliantaura.shtml) that looks something like this:

> [image]

[Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/brilliantaura.shtml) describes them as:

> As you play through the game, you will sometimes see Pokémon surrounded by a "brilliant aura". This golden coloured aura signifies that it has a special boost over certain Pokémon.

After you catch them though they seem to loose their aura. Do brilliant Pokémon stay brilliant after you catch them?

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. The brilliant aura is more of an indicator that these Pokémon are, on average, better than their standard counterparts in the wild. This is similar to the [White Swirl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322691/what-is-the-white-swirl-around-the-pok%C3%A9mon-on-the-map) in Pokémon Go indicating a Pokémon is boosted by the weather and has a higher maximum level on capture and higher base IV spread.

As Serebii as stated, brilliant Pokémon will have the following benefits:

- At least two guaranteed max IVs
- Guaranteed Egg Move
- Provides Watts

While they do lose their aura, they stay brilliant in the sense that these Pokémon have better chances of obtaining a better IV spread and do not need to be chain bred in order to gain specific moves.

Since you can transfer egg moves between Pokémon of the same species in this generation, you can potentially catch one with the egg move you want and transfer it over to your more optimized Pokémon (nature, IVs, EVs, etc).

Comment: Damn, I am always too slow on those questions. Well they are the low hanging fruit of easy to answer questions. 
But brilliant Pokemon do also have an higher level, which is implied in your answer but not specifically stated.
Overall it's usually worth more to try and get the Pokemon you want from den tho, since they can have up to 4 perfect IVs.

Comment: @Roybin93 The higher level wasn't stated in Serebii, but that's good to know :) But yes - if you're focused on IVs do raids.

Comment: Prior to the release of Pokémon Home, Brilliant Pokémon were the only way to obtain certain egg moves - for instance, Sparkling Aria on Lapras. Of course, now you can transfer Primarina into the game and just breed it down.